# How to save multiple entries in table using YapDatabase for swift

Tags: ios, swift, yapdatabase

I am using YapDatabase for storing my objects.Need how to store multiple entries in a table.

For example : I need to save all students information in Student table. So how can I do that with YapDatabase using Swift.

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

    let baseDir:String = paths.count > 0 ? paths[0] as String : NSTemporaryDirectory() as String

    let path = baseDir.stringByAppendingString("Database.sqlite")

    yapDB = YapDatabase(path: path)

    yapDataBaseConection = yapDB?.newConnection()

    yapDataBaseConection?.asyncReadWriteWithBlock({ transaction in




        }, completionBlock: {


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of examples on [YapDatabase Wiki](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/wiki/Hello-World)

First of all you should make a proper class that represents your student. You can read about it [in this article](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/wiki/Storing-Objects).

Then you should save an array of your students to database. `asyncReadWriteWithBlock` is okay.

```
for student in students {
    transaction.setObject(student, forKey:student.uniqueID, inCollection:"students")
}
```

That is all!

Another comlex task is to sort all the students and to show them in a UITableView. To make it work you should read about [View and Mappings](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/wiki/Views)

If you are looking for some swift examples - you can check [my sample project](https://bitbucket.org/iwheelbuy/test_improve). It is swift 2.3 compatible.

Hope it helps...